# Test data inserted to Prod Database how do i delete that record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, oracle-sqldeveloper

I mistakenly inserted few test records using PROD GUI, which got written to PROD Database. Is there a way to find what tables and column did those record touched ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. With a SELECT statement and a DELETE statement.

Comment: Thats funny, how would you know what all tables are updated with those records at the first place ?

Comment: By inspecting the source code of you GUI. Or by running a trace on the SQL Server while running the GUI. This tells you the objects used in the insert, as far as the exact rows, that needs visual inspection and analisis.

Comment: Can't you check the transaction log?

Comment: Use the SQL Server Profiler https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

Comment: do You have backup of database?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you don't have a running trace, CDC or other tracking mechanism enabled. So it seems like the following steps would be a reasonable solution:

1. Make sure that you can't find and drop that data from the
   Application GUI
2. Run SQL Profiler Trace using Tuning Template (it will give you enough information). Include ApplicationName and HostName columns to identify your connection.
3. Insert one more test record using UI (try to do the same operations as you did before)
4. Stop the trace and find the data you've inserted in it.
5. Identify other modification which was done from your application using ApplicationName, HostName, and SPID.
6. Create a SQL Script to delete those records.
7. Identify records which you had inserted before (probably they were inserted into the same tables)
8. Write a query to delete them too
9. Open transaction
10. Delete those records
11. Check that you have deleted only needed records
12. Commit transaction

UPD: according to the comment to this answer (with which I completely agree), if you have DEV or TEST environment on which you can do the same operation, do it and find modified records there. After that find modified records in the same tables on PROD.

P.S. I can not guarantee that following these steps you will be able to clean the data you've inserted, but probably you will be able to do this. I also recommend creating a full backup before deleting data.

Comment: I would suggest running these steps on dev or QA rather than prod to identify the tables the insert hit and test the deletion process. I would also suggest using roughly the same values as different values might mean different tables were involved.

Comment: Thank you for all of your input, I will try to follow those steps and see if that works. I had a conversation with one of my colleague who is the java developer and he recommended me to see how the source code at the front end and fields are mapped to the column of the table (SQL). What's your thought on that ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the code always works, but it could be more time expensive way, and it will be easier to miss something. But, as a benefit, you will not insert new data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have proper transaction logging enabled and using SQL Server 2008 and above. You can try using the [Change Data Capture Stored Procedures (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500244.aspx) and check the changes happened to the tables. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Well you could track through the code to see what tables it touches. Run Profiler on dev to see what code it sends or procs it calls when enter a new records the same way that you did on prod.

If you have formal PK and FK relationships, you likely will find out by trial and error because it won't let you delete the parent records until all the children are deleted. And test with some other record on the dev environment to figure out what tables might be involved. Or you could script the FKs to see what other tables are related to the parent table.

If you have auditing (as every Enterprise solution should have, but I digress), you can often find out by looking in the audit tables for transactions at that time. Our audit tables have both the datetime of the transaction and the user which makes it easier to filter for these things.

Of course if you know your data model, you should have a pretty good idea before you start. Or if you have a particular id that is in all the child tables and you do not have nice convenient FKs, then you could check out the system tables to find what tables have that column name. That assumes a fairly standard naming convention though. If you call the same column different things in different tables, yo u might miss some.

If you are using an ORM, there should be some way to check what tables are in the object related to the particular task you did. So if you inserted a test order of instance, check out what is contained in the order object.